# os_log not working in Xcproject old build with new Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, logging, xcode13

os_log api is being called in xcproj but was not able to see any logs in the console. It used to work in Xcode 12.x after I used Xcode13 RC then not able to see logs in the console

`os_log("%{public}@", log: log, type: type, message)` not logging any data to console

Comment: If you're logging from device, debug level may not appear in console, I used `info` instead and it worked.

Comment: was running proj on simulator was not able to see any logs on console.

Answer (score 0):

removed OS_ACTIVITY_MODE from scheme and build the project again then xcproject built on Xcode13 started showing logs on console